# How to wait for a function to be finished that is already running

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class that will do some network requests. On `init()` I load some initial data. So the class looks like this:

```
class NetworkHandler {
    init() {
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        // Do an asynchronous function to load initial data
    }
}
```

I pass an object of this class to a ViewController. In this ViewController I want to show a loading indicator until the initial load is finished. Next I want to show a normal screen. So like this:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
    var networkHandler: NetworkHandler?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if networkHandler.initialLoadIsDone {
            // Show something
        } else {
            // Show a loading indicator
            // Listen on networkHandlers initial load
            // On initial load done: Show somethin
        }
    }
}
```

So the first step if the initial load is finished or not I could handle with a local variable in networkHandler. But as I do not call the initial load function I cannot use a completionHandler to wait for the initial load to be finished. So I am wondering what's the best way to wait for the initial load to be finished? Also, can I replace the local variable solution by this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would suggest you refactor so that the load does not occur in the `init`. It is better if you have a function that initiates the load and then you can pass a closure to that function

Comment: @Paulw11what if I need the data in two possible screens? By doing so I could not use a closure again

Comment: If you have multiple observers then the typical pattern is to post a `Notification`

Answer (score 2):

Don't wait. Do notify.

For example use protocol / delegate to inform the target class about the stages

```
protocol NetworkHandlerProtocol {
    func didStartLoading()
    func didFinishInitialLoading(with data: Data)
}

class NetworkHandler {

    var delegate : NetworkHandlerProtocol

    init(delegate : NetworkHandlerProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func loadData() {
        delegate.didStartLoading()
        // Do an asynchronous function to load initial data
        let data = // some Data object
        delegate.didFinishInitialLoading(with: data)
    }
}
```

In the controller adopt the protocol and implement the methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var networkHandler = NetworkHandler(delegate : self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        networkHandler.loadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController : NetworkHandlerProtocol {

    func didStartLoading() { }

    func didFinishInitialLoading(with data: Data) { }

}
```

Comment: I thought about delegates. My problem: I want to start the network request already before the viewController appears to be ready to show the data on screen appearance without a loading bar.

Comment: You can call `loadData()` wherever you want.

Comment: Yes but what if loading finished before I set the delegate on my viewController? Then the didFinishInitialLoading() will never be called and I still want to know it on my viewController on appearance. Do I have to use a local variable var finishedLoading: Bool to do so? Or is there something more elegant?

Comment: When `loadData()` is called the delegate is already set. This is guaranteed by the  lazily instantiated variable `networkHandler`.

Comment: You could make the `loadData()` into a static func and add a completion handler to it, if you're not too interesting in anything besides it being complete. Otherwise delegates as suggested by @vadian.